# Is it possible to drop a cookie to all browsers in the client machine?

Tags: asp.net, cookies

Not only to the browser the request was made, but all the others. Or anywhere else which makes your server be aware of the same user.

Comment: God I hope not. Maybe with some kind of malware?

Comment: You mean no honest way to do that?

Comment: Really think about what you are asking here and what the implications might be if it were possible.

Comment: I just wanna be able to say Welcome asawyer, if he visits my site from another browser simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do this with cookies, but there are other sneaky ways around this via [evercookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evercookie) and techniques like it. One recent development has been [canvas-fingerprinting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_fingerprinting), which is probably too complicated for you to develop by yourself unless you have extensive canvas js experience. These techniques generally can be summed up as:

> don't use cookies, but rather innate properties of the users computer
>   such as fonts, graphics processing speed, mouse movement or others to
>   identify repeat-visit clients

If you don't have a lot of mobile clients, a very simple but error-prone way to do this is to just save your previously-visited ip addresses on the server and look up if that ip has visited before.

Please be aware, though, that using evercookies or similar techniques on your site may violate privacy guidelines, or possibly even laws in some places. You probably should not do this, but searching the terms above may give you some ideas.